# How to write regex to match pages and subdomains of one URL only?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get the following into a regex:

`*.foo.com/*`

#### success test cases

- www.foo.com
- www.foo.com/blah
- aaa.www.foo.com/woot/woot/woot

#### failure cases

- www.blah.com
- blah.com/ruroh

How would I write a regex to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A literal translation of your glob into regex is:

```
.*\.foo\.com(/.*)?
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, if you mean to test the sub-domains for foo.com:

`/(?<part>(w(?!ww)|w(?=[a-z0-9]{3,})|[a-vx-z0-9])[a-z0-9]*)\.foo\.com/`

Answer (score 0):

I have an easy regex that works:

```
(.*)\.foo\.com
```

You can easily test a regular expression yourself using [rubular](http://www.rubular.com). I strongly recommend it.